# Execution failed for task app:desugarDebugFileDependencies

Tags: android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Error while dexing.

Comment: Please add the details like Android Studio version and Gradle Version.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conflict when upgrading to the new desugar version (V2.0.0 in my case). I just deleted all the desugar folders in:

..\ProjectFolder\app\build\intermediates

The app then built properly.